# JSON Parse Error on line 1 column 1

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting:
`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`
when trying to parse an input string.

The input string is as follows:

```
{
    "data": [{
            "id": "1124647450995962",
            "name": "Softex HelloKity Jr.",
            "picture": {
                "data": {
                    "height": 256,
                    "is_silhouette": false,
                    "url": "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/c25.0.256.256\/10407468_575157839278262_6777986632930149130_n.jpg?oh=d18d635599e2c5b2175cd03765c96a8e&oe=5970D616",
                    "width": 256
                }
            }
        },
        ...
    ],
    "paging": {
        "next": "https:\/\/..."
    }
}
```

I cannot understand why I get an error on line 1 column 1. It seems to work fine with the following data:

```
var x = '{ "a" : [ 1,2,3] }';
var d = JSON.parse(x);
document.write(d.a);
```

Comment: Assuming the `, ...` isn't actually in your data, this __is__ valid `JSON`

Comment: Yeah, it is valid JSON. However, I am still  getting the error that something's wrong on line 1 column 1 (which I am assuming is the first character) which is the opening curly braces.

Comment: Are you entirely sure that the data above is still a string when it gets passed to `JSON.parse()`? If I do `JSON.parse({})`, it gives the same error which means this is most likely your problem. If you're using `jQuery` to retrieve this data, it might already have parsed it for you.